# Check Integrity of file while downloading

Tags: c#, hash, http-headers, httprequest, checksum

I am downloading various files from servers.I wish to verify integrity of file being downloaded.

 I would like to know if there are some headers or something in `HttpRequest` class that would give unique hash of the file which I would use to verify against file after download.

Answer (score 0):

Yes; According to [microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the HttpRequest Class contains some properties and methods you can use to verify the download

- [ContentLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.contentlength%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - Specifies the length, in bytes, of content sent by the client.
- [TimedOutToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.timedouttoken%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - Gets a CancellationToken object that is tripped when a request times out.
- [GetHashCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - Serves as the default hash function. (Inherited from Object.)